# Variable type conversion

Tags: java

I couldn't assign int variables into `char[]` array

I tried type casting, but it didn't work as I expected 
the complier keeps return me ASCII value which I didn't want them. I want the numbers the actual number

```
char[] char_array = new char[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
  int calculation = i * (d - 1);
  char_array[i] = (char) calculation;
}
```

After print out 
It gives me something like this

`|    B @ #`

Comment: `i *8 /2 ...;` isn't a valid Java expression

Comment: `System.out.print((int)'a');`

Comment: If you want the numbers, store them into an `int[]`. You're using `char[]`, which contains characters, and by default they're printed as characters instead of their numeric value.

Comment: Using System.out.print(calculation) returns aal the numbers just fine, but the problem is those values coudln't be converted into char type. Are there any ways to fix this? Thhank you.

Comment: No, i *8 /2 ...; is just the  example.  it was actually d * (d - 1)

Comment: Maybe I should delete this question

Comment: What do you mean by "something like this `|    B @ #`"? Is it something like `[B@ab47d2`? If so take a look at [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/409784)

Comment: If that is not the case then please provide [mcve] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) and *actual* results you are getting. Also include what *other* result you ware expecting (and why). Without it we need to play guessing game which is not very efficient way of solving problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `char` to store numeric values. Its because when your store an int value to a char variable type conversion occurs as follows:

```
char i = 60 + 5;
```

> Here, i will store `A` which has Unicode value `65`.

Similarly, when you store a char value to an int, type conversion occurs as follows:

```
int i = 'A'
```

> This will store 65;

This is how java performs type cast between int and char;

So, to deal with this situation, use the following code:

```
int[] int_array = new int[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
int calculation = i *8 /2 ...;
int_array[i] = calculation;
}
```

or you can also use `double` if you want precise results;

Comment: Java doesn't use ASCII. `char` is a UTF-16 code unit. UTF-16 is one of several character encodings for the Unicode character set.

Answer (score 0):

try, this should help you.

```
int a = 1
char b = Integer.toString(a).charAt(0);
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: I just realized that char only accept 1 position value.

Answer (score 0):

For printing number, you should cast the output to `int`.

```java
char[] char_array = new char[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
  int calculation = i * 4;
  char_array[i] = (char) calculation;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
    System.out.println( (int) char_array[i] );
}
```

But in this case consider to use a `int[]` directly instead casting forth and back.

Also note, that overflow can happen when storing `char c = (int) 256`.